# Expected number of hearts

Tags: probability

I draw 13 cards from a deck and five are hearts. If you also draw 13 cards next how many hearts do you expect?

My approach: P(heart in 1 draw) = 8/39 since there are only 8 hearts remaining

Expected no. of hearts in 13 draws = 8/39 * 13 = 8/3  = 2.67

Is this right? I believe the first part is meant to confuse you into thinking its 5

This is an interview question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's correct. The number of hearts is the sum of indicators $I_j = $ "the $j$th next card is a heart". Clearly those are symmetric and $I_j = 1$ with probability $\frac{8}{39}$. By linearity of expectation, the answer is $13 \times \frac{8}{39}$.

Comment: Isn't the probability that the $j^{\mathrm{th}}$ card is a heart conditional on whether or not the $(j-1)^{\mathrm{st}}$ card was a heart?

Comment: @kandb By symmetry, if the deck is well shuffled, it doesn't matter which card you look at. It is a equally probable to be a heart independent of its place.

Comment: And if we apply same logic, probability of each card to be a non-hearth is 31/39, and final result raise to 8/3 Hearth+31/3non-Hearth. 8/3+31/3=13. It makes sens. If total was not 13, we should reconsider our process.